# jquery and and remove class is not working

Tags: php, jquery, html

I am trying to use jquery to hide and show elements in WooCommerce based of the variation ID. I did a test and received the alert when the ID is activated. However, when I add in the removeClass and addClass nothing happens.

Tested the code using alert and that works

This is a snippet of the function:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_quantity', 'display_dropdown_variation_add_cart' );

function display_dropdown_variation_add_cart() {

   global $product;
    $product_id = $product->get_id();

    if( $product_id == 8444 ){

      ?>
      <script>
      jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

         $('input.variation_id').change( function(){
            if( '' != $('input.variation_id').val() ) {

               var var_id = $('input.variation_id').val();

              if ((var_id == 8543) || (var_id == 8539) ||(var_id == 8540) || (var_id == 8541) || (var_id == 8542) ||
              (var_id == 8544) || (var_id == 8545) ||(var_id == 8546) || (var_id == 8547) || (var_id == 8548)) {

              alert('Round Trip' + var_id);

              $('#art').removeClass('hidden');
              $('#art').('input').attr('required', true);

              $('#owd').addClass("hidden");
              $('#owd').('input').attr('required', false);

              $('#owa').addClass("hidden");
              $('#owa').('input').attr('required', false);            
            } 

            }  
        });

    });
      </script>
      <?php

   }

}
```

Comment: Why not just use `.show()` and `.hide()`?

Comment: Thanks. Let me try that and update the post.

Comment: @ Nick .show() and .hide() did work, but caused other issues as I had to hide the elements on initial load.

Comment: You might be able to work around that by using `.toggle` with argument true for show and false for hide? But it seems you have a solution...

Comment: Thanks. I will test that too. the solution works fine though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think you have error on:

```
$('#art').removeClass('hidden');
$('#art').('input').attr('required', true);

$('#owd').addClass("hidden");
$('#owd').('input').attr('required', false);

$('#owa').addClass("hidden");
$('#owa').('input').attr('required', false);
```

try change your selector to:

```
$('#art').removeClass('hidden');
$('#art input').attr('required', true);

$('#owd').addClass("hidden");
$('#owd input').attr('required', false);

$('#owa').addClass("hidden");
$('#owa input').attr('required', false);
```